How do I make a different interval for the appearance of balls?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManagerX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] ballPrefabs;

    private float spawnLimitXLeft = -40;
    private float spawnLimitXRight = 5;
    private float spawnPosY = 30;

    private float startDelay = 1.0f;
    private float spawnInterval = 4;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnRandomBall", startDelay, spawnInterval);
    }

    // Spawn random ball at random x position at top of play area
    void SpawnRandomBall ()
    {
        // Generate random ball index and random spawn position
        Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(spawnLimitXLeft, spawnLimitXRight), spawnPosY, 0);

        // instantiate ball at random spawn location

        int ballIndex = Random.Range(0, ballPrefabs.Length);
        Instantiate(ballPrefabs[ballIndex], spawnPos, ballPrefabs[ballIndex].transform.rotation);
    }

}

I need to make an appearance for example from 3 to 5 seconds, the Random.Range method does not work for some reason

InvokeRepeating always has a fixed interval. You can use a Coroutine instead and vary the time waited between iterations:
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnRandomBall(startDelay, spawnIntervalMin, spawnIntervalMax));
}

// Spawn random ball at random x position at top of play area
IEnumerator SpawnRandomBall (float startDelay, float spawnIntervalMin, float spawnIntervalMax)
{
    // Tell unity to pause this function for "startDelay" seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startDelay);

    // Repeat infinitely. If you don't want to, change the "true" to a different condition
    while (true) {
        // Generate random ball index and random spawn position
        Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(spawnLimitXLeft, spawnLimitXRight), spawnPosY, 0);

        // instantiate ball at random spawn location
        int ballIndex = Random.Range(0, ballPrefabs.Length);
        Instantiate(ballPrefabs[ballIndex], spawnPos, ballPrefabs[ballIndex].transform.rotation);

        // Tell Unity to pause this function for Random.Range(spawnIntervalMin, spawnIntervalMax) seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(spawnIntervalMin, spawnIntervalMax));
    }
}

